# Project using both Astro and Laravel

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code, build, project, astrojs

I am planning a website that will be mostly a brochure site using Astro. A feature of the site will be a small Laravel app. My question is should I build these as two separate projects with links between them, or can they be combined as a single project. If the latter, would I start with an Astro project and somehow insert the Laravel project into it, or start with a Laravel build with Astro inside of it.

I have tried to find resources for doing this with no luck.  Laravel has docs for working with Vue, React and Svelte, but that's mostly SPA stuff. Pointers to any resources that discuss this would be welcome as well.

Comment: My opinion - this must be diffident projects, because astro is not spa and if you need something which work with backend - you must choose something else.

Comment: I believe the best solution for you it's using Inertia + Vue.